# Spring MVC forward to another URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, proxy

I create a web-application with Spring 4. It must work as proxy for internal resources of our company. 
When it receives user requests, it analyses its correctness and user privilegies, and if everything is correct, gives user the result.

So, is it possible to do forward request to page like http://xxxxx.com:8983/solr?
If yes, show the example, please
So that user writes url of my application and sees the page http://xxxxx.com:8983/solr

P.S. I tried to find it in google, but everywhere were answers about redirect but not forward

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think there are multiple ways of dealing with this.  But my gut feeling is that you're going to have to write some code yourself.

Basically, I would use HttpClient to make a request to your proxied website, take the input stream from the httpclient connection and stream it to the output stream of your spring application response.

You could handle all this interaction in the controller itself, but I think using a specialized ViewResolver might be better.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I also tried to use RestTemplate and HttpURLConnection, but they were too slow. Browser showed pages immediately, they did requests for pages for 5 seconds, and only then user saw them. Because of this fact i interested about forwarding. Will HttpClient be fast enough?

Comment: Don't know how fast HttpClient will be.  There are lots of factors to that question that are difficult to answer.  There are lots of ways of configuring HttpClient and the most important thing is to make sure that you're using a mutlithreaded connection manager.  Then from there, you're just going to have to try it out.  You can try and use URLConnection directly, but I think HttpClient uses that under the covers anyways.  You could also consider using a different proxy mechanism.  Perhaps there is some Apache HTTPD plugin you could use?  Apache HTTPD is fast and super easy for proxy work.

Comment: I don't know about apache httpd plugin, because i need Java application that reads user privilegies from database and then will provide REST service and web interface besides proxy. The biggest question is about network. The same link is opened in browser 5 times faster. What to do with it?

Comment: I understand the first part of your comment.  But the second part.  What link is opened up 5x faster?  Do you mean your solr link is 5x faster when accessed directly vs access via the java proxy?  I would find that hard to believe.  There would have to be some serious coding issues.  You are going to have to empirically measure everything.  I recommend a firefox plugin called LORI and using a java profiler tool, like YourKit or JProfile.  Don't use them all at the same time btw, measure request speed without a profiler, then with the profiler measure what is occurring in the java code.

Comment: It's really hard to believe. But proxy works not only with solr, besides it proxy works with lily. I tested with lily. And it was really so. I didn't find anything in the internet. Ok, i will try to use profiler and plugin. And HttpClient instead of RestTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
return "forward:/page/section/";
```